# Spring-boot handle NoHandlerException in @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception, handlerexceptionresolver

I want to handle NoHandlerException in Springboot app and return a custom error message. I added following to my application.properties and tried to override the error message.

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Error doesn't hit the @ControllerAdvice... It is handled in defaulthandlerexceptionresolver . Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on the handler, let me know if this works.

Comment: It didn't work in My controller advice, "ResponseEntityExceptionHandler" is extended. So I'm not using @ExceptionHandler except I have to override the method.

Comment: OK then put on its head these annotations: `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: you can refer https://github.com/s2agrahari/global-excpetion-handler-spring-boot  for global exception handling for rest apis.

Comment: Thanx, @JonathanJohx, it worked. Can you please add it as an answer ? So this would be useful for others as well. How ever, Thank you very much saved a lot of my time...

Comment: Sure, I will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`and `@ControllerAdvice` on the exceptions handler head, it means:

**@ControllerAdvice**

> Specialization of @Component for classes that declare @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, or @ModelAttribute methods to be shared across multiple @Controller classes.

**@Order**

> Defines the sort order for an annotated component. If we put as **Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE** which is useful constant for the highest precedence value.

The code should be shown like this:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionsHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    .....
}
```

**REFERENCES:**

[@ControllerAdvice annotation documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

[@Order annotation documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)