# How to override handleMethodArgumentNotValid properly in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, overriding

I'm trying to override the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method. But I'm still getting the error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]`

I've overridden the method as suggested in various posts (for example in [Spring Rest ErrorHandling @ControllerAdvice / @Valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651160/spring-rest-errorhandling-controlleradvice-valid)) like this:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    @ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest webRequest) {
        String message = errorMessageBuilder(ex);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, webRequest);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Sincerely,

Marcel

Comment: The error message mentions ambiguity. That sounds like there are multiple exception handlers for the same exception class and the compiler won't pick a random one. I have no idea about a solution though.

Comment: I know what the message means, Spring handles it internally as well, that's why I'm overriding it (Extending the class at first, then override it.)

Comment: @MarcelOostebring please check my answer, this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961101/10426557 if this helps upvote please...

Comment: @One guy that unfortunately did not help me. I'm still getting the ambigious exception handler method mapped error.

Comment: May help someone, I got it working with this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68888906/3412696

Comment: I think the Spring boot version is causing the problem. Unfortunately, in some of tutorials the versions are not mentioned and the speed of change is insane these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create your own response, then try with the below code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("error", ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}
```

You can change the Map to your customize object and set the error pieces of information you want. I hope it will work.

Comment: Yes, I've found a working way by now. Either not extending the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, or if you do extend that class, remove @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class) worked too.